# How the get the text value of a complete value of a variable?

Tags: string, text-properties, print

here a little example to explain my problem :

How to get "marge" or ("marge") from oef-highlighted-variable ?

```
oef-highlighted-variable
#("marge" 0 5 (fontified nil face oef-font-variable-name-face))
```

With `replace-regexp-in-string` or Is there a better way ?

**SOLVED by wasamasa**

```
(substring-no-properties oef-highlighted-variable)
"marge"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Emacs displays a propertized string.  It contains of the text "marge", but also has the properties `fontified` and `face` applied from position 0 to 5.  If you pass it to other string handling functions, it will be handled the same, with the exception of those that look up string properties (such as `equal-including-properties` which compares them, `string-equal` however doesn't).

If you're still bothered by this, you can use `substring-no-properties` to obtain a string without them.